# How user can Read/Write DWG files from realDWG developing competing application?

Tags: .net, gis, autocad, autocad-plugin, dwg

We are planning to develop a 3D CAD/ GIS application. It would have an interface similar to AutoCAD.

1. It would have following features
2. 3D CAD model space
3. CAD edit tools
4. GIS data import and export tools
5. Support file exchange formats - DWG, IFC, SHP, DXF, PDF, SQLITE, etc
6. Pointcloud support
7. Handling large dataset

Answer (score 0):

AutoCAD OEM should be a better choice if you need an UI similar to AutoCAD but there is no support for IFC.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Maxence [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38243482/4838205), AutoCAD OEM will allow you to fully customize the UI with your own, but requires a special business agreement.

Alternatively you can just create a "regular" AutoCAD plugin ([.NET, C++, LISP, VBA](http://www.autodesk.com/developautocad)) that perform customization on the UI and can include some commands, this plugin/app can then be published and sold through [Autodesk App Store](https://apps.autodesk.com/).

Finally, AutoCAD is available as a webservice called [Design Automation](https://developer.autodesk.com/), in case you just want to batch-process files on the cloud. It can also be viewed on the browser ([see Viewer](https://developer.autodesk.com/)).